# How to find $E[X],E[Y]$ for the following story?

Tags: probability, expected-value

A gambler goes to the casino and plays a slot machine, he tells himself that he will only play 5 rounds, but if he wins the 5th round he keeps playing until he lose.

let $0< p < 1$ be the gambler's probabilty to win a single round, **X** is the number of rounds he played and **Y** the number of rounds he lost.

how can i calcuate E[X] and E[Y]?

***My thoughts:***

I know that the gambler will play at least 5 rounds in every situation,so i know there's Geometric Distribution from the 5th round, but i dont really know how to proceed.

Comment: There are two aspects which don´t motivate me to answer: Firstly, you haven´t post any thoughts. And secondly, you haven´t accepted any answers at your 8 questions.

Comment: @callculus actually had some thoughts, I know that the gambler will play at least 5 rounds in every situation,so i know there's Geometric Distribution from the 5th round, but i dont really know how to proceed.

Comment: I´ve noticed that you´ve followed my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be another (virtual) gambler (with the same chance of winning in a round)
who decides to play until his first loss has arrived and let $Z$
denote the number of rounds he plays.

Then we can say that $X$ has the same distribution as $5+UZ$ where
$U=1$ if the original gambler wins the fifth round and $U=0$ otherwise.

Moreover $U$ and $Z$ are independent so that: $$\mathbb{E}X=5+\mathbb{E}U\mathbb{E}Z$$

Can you find $\mathbb{E}Z$ and $\mathbb{E}U$ yourself?

---

If $V$ denotes the number of losses of the original gambler in the
first $4$ rounds then the total number of losses  will be $1+V$ so that $$\mathbb EY=1+\mathbb EV$$
This because the first loss after the first $4$ rounds will make him end the game.

Can you find $\mathbb{E}V$ yourself?